# Transiting through Heathrow airport with a Bangladeshi passport and Canadian Student Visa

Tags: visas, uk, transit, paperwork, bangladeshi-citizens

I would be helped a lot if you could answer to my question.

Would I be able to transit through Heathrow airport without a transit visa for travelling to India from Canada having a Canadian Student Visa on Bangladeshi passport? I would have a layover of 4 hours.

I have read that a passenger from a certain group of countries having a Canadian visa would be able to transit through Heathrow airport with any visa. I want to be sure of my finding.

Much thanks. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that a passenger from a certain group of countries having a Canadian visa would be able to transit through Heathrow airport with any visa

Wrong: **all** nationalities with a Canadian visa can transit the UK without a visa.

So yes, you can do this trip.